Where to find the web client hosting file editor view in the Zoho Catalyst console?
I can view the function editor for my node.js function in the Catalyst console. But, I am struggling to find the option to view my react client files in the console?
Does anyone find the option in the Catalyst console?

Currently, there is no option available to view the web client hosting files directly from the Catalyst console. You need to download the client zip and open it in your preferred IDE in your machine.
Also, note since you are using a framework such as React, only the compiled files will be hosted in the Catalyst server. Even if you download your client zip, you will not get your source files. so, maintain your framework source code files in you git for future use.
